# What techniques can I use make my implementation of mergesort run faster?

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm trying to figure out ways to make my implementation of mergesort run faster. Currently I have implemented it recursively using deques in Python, as you can see below.

The logic is to split into halves until we have a list of size 1, convert that to a deque and then take advantage of the double-ended nature of deques to popleft rather than pop(0) on a list. We have deques all the way back up until the final deque is the same length as the original list; that deque is then turned back into a list.

```py
from collections import deque

def mergesort(iterable, final_length=False):
    '''
    Return a new list containing all items from the iterable in ascending order.

    This uses a custom implementation of mergesort that utilises a deque.
    final_length should not be input and is there to ensure the final deque 
    produced gets converted to a list.
    '''

    if not final_length:
        final_length = len(iterable)

    if len(iterable) <= 1:
        return iterable

    l1 = iterable[:len(iterable)//2]
    l2 = iterable[len(iterable)//2:]

    ml1 = mergesort(l1, final_length)
    ml2 = mergesort(l2, final_length)

    ml = merge(ml1, ml2)

    return ml if len(ml) < final_length else list(ml)

def merge(l1, l2):
    '''
    Return a sorted, merged deque of two input values or deques.
    '''
    l3 = deque()

    if len(l1) == 1:
        l1 = deque(l1)
    if len(l2) == 1:
        l2 = deque(l2)

    while l1 and l2:
        if l1[0] < l2[0]:
            l3.append(l1.popleft())
        else:
            l3.append(l2.popleft())

    while l1 and not l2:
        l3.append(l1.popleft())

    while l2 and not l1:
        l3.append(l2.popleft())

    return l3
```

But unfortunately it runs a lot slower than the builtin timsort algorithm.

```
num_items,time(s),algorithm
1000,0.00017970000000033792,builtin
1000,0.006608100000001116,mergesort
499000,0.33416399999987334,builtin
499000,4.807901299999912,mergesort
```

I appreciate that timsort is incredibly efficient and utilises lower level code and so will generally be faster, but is there anything specific I'm missing here that's making my code run so slowly?

I'm not particularly looking for a full working solution but rather some general discussion and tips.

Comment: `iterable[:len(iterable)//2]` and `iterable[len(iterable)//2:]` copy slices of `iterable`, and then in the `merge` function you copy those into a `deque` once again. Reduce the number of list copies. E.g. create a working copy initially and from then on only pass start-/end indices in the recursive function.

Comment: Your code runs interpreted whereas builtin sort is compiled. It could very well explain all of the speed difference. You could try to compile your sort algorithm, for instance using [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org)'s just in time compilation (@njit decorator).

Comment: @simonz Thanks, I did this but it actually slowed it down. It takes twice as long generally but on the plus size the space complexity is reduced. Do you know why it is taking so much longer? [gist](https://gist.github.com/ChrisKneller/f99f34fbb63dc9b81da7ec9d4d6e42ca)

Comment: @Keldorn thanks! I have never heard of this compiler but I will explore it now